# How to jar a javafx application in eclipse which uses a css stylesheet

Tags: java, css, javafx-2, javafx

i have a javafx application which uses a css stylesheet to set the background of the applciation and the effects on the buttons.

When i try to export this javafx application to a runnable jar in eclipse,the jar file does not contain the css styles sheet and images needed.

I have tried putting the css and images inside the jars manually but no luck

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Can You show project structure?
Where You put css files in sources and how You attach it to scene?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the JavaFX packager support else you won't be able to run the jar because JavaFX is not on the classpath!

I'd suggest you use [e(fx)clipse](http://www.efxclipse.org/) and its support for export as shown in the [tutorial 1](http://www.efxclipse.org/trac/wiki/Tutorial1)